# graphene-django converts models.BigInteger() to graphene.Integer()

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

I'm using graphene-django.

I'm trying to retrieve data from a `models.BigInteger()` field, but when I make the query in graphiQL I get the error

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Int cannot represent non 32-bit signed integer value: 2554208328"
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "match": null
  }
}
```

Anyone know how I can force graphene to give me the data?

Answer (score 6):

I ended up using a custom scalar.    It'd be nicer if this was automatically converted to a better scalar within graphene-django, but here's how I fixed this.  I wrote a converter.py file with the custom BigInt scalar, which uses a float rather than an int, if we have a number larger than the MAX_INT

```
# converter.py
from graphene.types import Scalar
from graphql.language import ast
from graphene.types.scalars import MIN_INT, MAX_INT

class BigInt(Scalar):
    """
    BigInt is an extension of the regular Int field
        that supports Integers bigger than a signed
        32-bit integer.
    """
    @staticmethod
    def big_to_float(value):
        num = int(value)
        if num > MAX_INT or num < MIN_INT:
            return float(int(num))
        return num

    serialize = big_to_float
    parse_value = big_to_float

    @staticmethod
    def parse_literal(node):
        if isinstance(node, ast.IntValue):
            num = int(node.value)
            if num > MAX_INT or num < MIN_INT:
                return float(int(num))
            return num
```

then

```
# schema.py
from .converter import BigInt
class MatchType(DjangoObjectType):
    game_id = graphene.Field(BigInt)
    class Meta:
        model = Match
        interfaces = (graphene.Node, )
        filter_fields = {}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can register new converter:

```
    import graphene
    from graphene_django.converter import convert_django_field

    @convert_django_field.register(models.BigIntegerField)
    def convert_bigint_to_float(field, registry=None):
        return graphene.Float(description=field.help_text, required=not field.null)
```

This is the way it's used in graphene-django itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the graphene source code (but not yet released I guess):
https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/485b1ed325287fd721b13aac8b4ec872d6295c6a/graphene/types/scalars.py#L85

```
class BigInt(Scalar):
"""
The `BigInt` scalar type represents non-fractional whole numeric values.
`BigInt` is not constrained to 32-bit like the `Int` type and thus is a less
compatible type.
"""

@staticmethod
def coerce_int(value):
    try:
        num = int(value)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            num = int(float(value))
        except ValueError:
            return None
    return num

serialize = coerce_int
parse_value = coerce_int

@staticmethod
def parse_literal(ast):
    if isinstance(ast, IntValueNode):
        return int(ast.value)
```